# Dismissing UIViewController messes up notifications

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, observer-pattern, nsnotificationcenter

I have a button on the first view controller of my app that simply displays another view controller on the storyboard via a segue. This present view controller shall be referred to as GameViewController.

During the time when GameViewController is visible, a lot happens, including sending notifications via NSNotificationCenter, governed by a just one member object of GameViewController. This all works perfectly and as it should be.

At a certain point, the GameViewController is dismissed returning to the first view controller of my app. I then tap the button again and GameViewController is again presented, but it's time for the first notification to be sent, I get a selector not found runtime error.

I am not sure what causes this, but I'm guessing it has something to do with observers being added more than one time.

Comment: Remove observers when you are returning to previous viewcontroller. Best would be to do it in viewWillDissappear or viewDidDissappear.

Comment: @IxPaka Is there a way to remove all observers at once as I cannot exactly reference them from the GameViewController?

Comment: @IxPaka Looks like I'm going to have to do it for each object individually. Thanks.

Comment: i recommend removing the notifications before they are set as well, making sure that they only get fired once - also your problem sounds like the function/selector that the notification is looking for cannot be found, perhaps even the instance containing the selector is now gone and has been replaced with another identical instance - i would recommend separating all your notification code and placing it outside of the view controllers themselves, so the notifications don't depend on a specific view controller being present

Comment: Thanks. Feel free to leave this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)dealloc 
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```